# remove console Typed Text in C# Console-Application

Tags: c#, console-application

How can i clear this rows. like "CLS" command in CMD. thanks.
[image: I don't want to show this lines]

Comment: Have you tried [Clear()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.clear?view=netframework-4.8) ?

Comment: why my Picture don't show?

Comment: I see a picture, though I think it is unnecessary. If you don't see it then the request could be blocked by whatever hardware/software is between you and the Internet. Can you see images on other SO questions?

Comment: It looks like the program is printing that line...

Comment: @Crowcoder no i can't see

Answer (score 5):

```
Console.Clear();
```

> [Clears](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.clear?view=netframework-4.8) the console buffer and corresponding console window of display
>   information.